# How to draw string with different color per char

Tags: c#, .net

Yes, I know it is possible to use RichTextBox for that. Is there are any alternative solution?

Edit: The problem with use of DrawString function by char is that it will not show string properly in total

Comment: see this link [Multiple colors in a C# .NET label](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275836/multiple-colors-in-a-c-net-label)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [override the OnPaint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cksxshce%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) method, but I don't think you want to take it that far (I may be wrong).

Short answer, use a richtext.

Comment: at the end I have selected RTF with delayed coloring