# VB.NET multi color Label

Tags: vb.net

I wanted to have multiple color for text in single label controller

e.g.

`label1.Text = " $ 480.00 "`

What I want is character `$` in Red color and other digits or character after `$` in color blue.

I cannot have separate labels for digits and `$`.

Comment: Is this for win forms, web, WPF?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple colors in a C# .NET label](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275836/multiple-colors-in-a-c-sharp-net-label)

Comment: Please read this [post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275836/multiple-colors-in-a-c-sharp-net-label

Answer (score 3):

The label itself can't do that, so you can either use a read-only RichTextBox control, or just make your own label control.

In it's simplest form:

```
Public Class ColorLabel
  Inherits Control

  Private _Money As Decimal = 0

  Property Money() As Decimal
    Get
      Return _Money
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
      _Money = value
      Me.Invalidate()
    End Set
  End Property

  Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnPaint(e)

    Dim moneyText As String = String.Format("{0:N2}", _Money)
    Dim dollarWidth As Integer = TextRenderer.MeasureText(e.Graphics, "$", Me.Font).Width
    Dim moneyWidth As Integer = TextRenderer.MeasureText(e.Graphics, moneyText, Me.Font).Width

    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "$", Me.Font, New Point(Me.ClientSize.Width - (dollarWidth + moneyWidth + 2), 2), Color.Red)
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, moneyText, Me.Font, New Point(Me.ClientSize.Width - (moneyWidth + 2), 2), Color.Blue)
  End Sub

End Class
```

Result:

[image]