# partially colored label in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, label

I'm trying to show a word in a label with a single colored letter for example :

> He[**l**]lo

( which the specified **l** is red )

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no native control in .NET(`winform`) that does this.try this [Label With multiple colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275836/multiple-colors-in-a-c-sharp-net-label)