# Change string color

Tags: c#, winforms

I have label that contain of several strings and one of those string i want to change it color.

This is what i have try:

```
private string state = string.Empty;
state = System.Drawing.Color.Blue.ToString();
```

But it still remained to same color

Comment: That's because `Blue.ToString()` returns the text `"Blue"` and not actually the blue color. See if there isn't a `Label.ForeColor` member or similar

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple colors in a C# .NET label](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275836/multiple-colors-in-a-c-sharp-net-label)

Comment: Can you add more clarifications , put your entire code please

Comment: what kind of logic has the OP given? :)

Answer (score 8):

As far as I'm aware, a Windows Forms `Label` can only use a single color for the whole of its text. If you want multi-colored text, you'll either need to use multiple labels or use [`RichTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx)... or perform the painting yourself, of course.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the colour of the label, not the string.

So you'd have a label on your form, say `LabelTest`, then in your code would look like this:

```
string state = "Some text for our label";
LabelTest.Text = state;
LabelTest.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
```

As has been mentioned in other answers, to use multiple colours, you'd need multiple labels, each with their text and colour set separately.

Answer (score 1):

Label cannot contain items of more than one color. Use more labels or some other kind of control. But from the code you pasted I recommend to go through some .NET tutorial. You probably miss the basic concepts.

Answer (score 0):

//this is for label color

```
Label1.Text.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

//this for text`enter code here`

```
Label1.Text.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```