# c# web forms how to take two or more colors in one label text

Tags: c#, winforms

```
label1.Text = "welcome to stackoverflow'" + textbox1.text + "'";
label1.ForeColor = Color.Green;
```

i want to take `textbox1.text` has diffrent color how to take that diffrent color in win forms?. 
in web forms that has to take  tag, but in win forms it was not working?

regads,
nagarjuna.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible. You could either use a richtextbox and remove borders and make it non editable so it looks like a label or use a HTML control and use HTML markup.

Here's a xaml example of using a richtextbox like a label

```
<RichTextBox BorderStyle="none" Enabled="true" ReadOnly="true" Height="160" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="43,20,0,0" Name="richTextBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="258" TextChanged="richTextBox1_TextChanged">
    <FlowDocument xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
        <Paragraph>
            <Run Foreground="Red">Red</Run>
            <Run Foreground="Green">Green</Run>
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

Here's a code example

```
Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
Run run1 = new Run("welcome to stackoverflow ");
run1.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
Run run2 = new Run(textbox1.text);
run2.Foreground = Brushes.Green;
para.Inlines.Add(run1);
para.Inlines.Add(run2);
// Get the document
FlowDocument doc = richTextBox1.Document;
// Clear existing content
doc.Blocks.Clear();
// Add new content
doc.Blocks.Add(para);
```

Comment: i need execute that button event, in that time  "welcome to stackoverflow"green color+"textbox.text"+ red color is its possible

Comment: Yes its possible.  Just declare para, run1, run2 and doc at the class level.  Then in the onclick method of the button add something like:

     Private void btn_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            run2 = new Run(textbox1.text);
            para = new Paragraph();
            para.Inlines.Add(run1);
            para.Inlines.Add(run2);           
            doc.Blocks.Clear();
            doc.Blocks.Add(para);
    }

Comment: what is flow document in richtextbox

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is no native control in .NET(`winform`) that adds multiple colors to label but you can try this [Label With multiple colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275836/multiple-colors-in-a-c-sharp-net-label?rq=1][1])