# How do I highlight a string that is an attribute of an object?

Tags: c#, winforms, stringbuilder

I have a car class with four attributes (colour, model, mileage, year) and I get these attributes from four text boxes. I then assign these attributes to a new object of the car class and assign this new object to an object array in the car class. I need to be able to highlight the mileage attribute but I am outputting in a string builder like this it like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    carColourIN = colour.Text;
    carModelIN = model.Text;
    carMileageIN = Double.Parse(mileage.Text);
    carYearIN = Int32.Parse(year.Text);

    Car user = new Car(carColourIN, carModelIN, carMileageIN, carYearIN);

    Car.vehicles[i] = user;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


    sb.Append("Colour: " + Car.vehicles[i].CarColour + "\nModel: " + Car.vehicles[i].CarModel + "\nMileage: " + Car.vehicles[i].CarMileage
                    + "\nYear: " + Car.vehicles[i].CarYear + "\n\n");

    displayLabel.Text = sb.ToString();
    i++;
}
```

how would I highlight the mileage attribute in the appended string builder so that either the background of that particular section of text is a different colour or the actual text is.

Comment: You'd need to use a `RichTextBox` instead of a `Label` to have parts of the text coloured.

Comment: And if I used a RichTextBox, how exactly do I highlight the attribute if I am adding it to the string builder like this: `Car.vehicles[i].CarMileage`

Comment: Or you could owner-draw the Label.

Comment: @dusk42 - You set the colour based on position after you've assigned the `.Text` property. It's a bit annoying. There's no markup that you can apply.

Comment: i think you can do something like this displayLabel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green or Car.vehicles[i].CarColour;

Comment: _You set the colour based on position after you've assigned the .Text property._ Actually you select the portion you want to color and then set the SelectionColor. __Never__ directly set the Text property or you will mess up all previous formatting.

Answer (score 1):

I see a few different options. The answers to this question [Multiple Colors in C# Label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275836/multiple-colors-in-a-c-sharp-net-label) explain the first two options.

**Option 1:** Do not use your StringBuilder, and use a rich text box. Then loop through the properties and add them one at a time using the `rtb_AppendText` function in the provided link.

**Option 2:** Create a custom label control and override the `OnPaint` method. In the OnPaint method you can use MeasureText and DrawString to accomplish your goal.

**Option 3:** Create a user control with four different labels, this way you could control the color/font/appearance of each label, and in the long run gives you the most flexibility.